# Допустимо ли использовать разговорную речь на форуме?

Tags: лексика, общие-вопросы, лексическая-сочетаемость

Является ли это ошибкой или это норма и ошибкой разговорную речь на форуме считать нельзя?

**P.S.** Я имею в виду более неформальный форум, чем этот.

Answer (score 4):

Разгово́рная речь — функциональный стиль речи, его основные особенности указаны в Википедии.[Разговорный стиль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/)
Форумы же бывают разные, данный форум, к примеру, имеет  лингвистический характер, потому основным стилем является научный.

В то же время здесь, я думаю,  могут допускаться **отдельные элементы разговорного стиля**, которые делают общение более живым и эмоциональным.

В то же время на таких форумах недопустима лексика грубая или просторечная, неформальное обращение к участникам и т.д.

Comment: Vera, иногда приходится и грубые слова использовать: некоторые участники прямо выводят из себя. Иначе никак.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае на этот вопрос нет ответа, т.к. форум — это очень широкое понятие. Ориентируйтесь на тот стиль речи, который используется другими участниками форума. На большинстве форумов есть страница с правилами поведения. Например, на этом сайте:

- [Какое поведение ожидается от пользователей?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)
- [Будьте дружелюбными](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не упомянули конкретный форум, поэтому сложно что-либо говорить. Вообще, если на форуме обсуждаются научные вопросы, то всё-таки рекомендуется использовать научный стиль речи. Но на нашем форуме можно порой и разговорный стиль увидеть :)

Answer (score 0):

In Roma prudenter quasi cives romanus

или ее русскй вариант - вполне ответ "да" на вопрос. Меру только надо знать, в натуре!